# Create subset of array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array of more than 10 items. What I need is to send a set of 10 values to a URL to return some `JSON` data. Save this `JSON` feed and send set of next 10 values (or the remaining ones) to that same URL and this continues until all the items are iterated.

More specifically how I can divide an array to subsets of 10 items each.

```
Array ( [0] => 249 [1] => 2827 [2] => 3228 [3] => 3327 [4] => 3567 [5] => 4259 [6] => 4547 [7] => 4607 [8] => 4660 [9] => 4677 [10] => 4783 [11] => 4807 [12] => 4934 [13] => 4944 [14] => 4977 [15] => 4990 [16] => 4992 [17] => 5021 [18] => 5056 [19] => 5061 )
```

Comment: Adding your code will help us in helping you

Comment: Try using `array_slice`: http://ro1.php.net/array_slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function.

To example:

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_chunk`.

[php.net/array_chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk)

Something like:

```
$my_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

// Divide into chunks of 2 (last chunk may contain less than 2)
$chunks = array_chunk($my_array, 2); 

// Loop through chunks (two items at a time)
while ($chunk = array_pop($chunks)) {
    // Do something with the next chunk
    var_dump($chunk);
}
```